# Check if variable is undefined not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if a variable is undefined and quickly found some stackoverflow answers that said the correct way to do it is to test if(variable==null).  But in Chrome I am getting an error saying:
Uncaught ReferenceError: xdate is not defined

Huh? The whole reason I am testing is so I don't get errors like this.  And I did it just like the approved stackoverflow answers.
Here is my code snippet.

```
        if (xdate == null){
          var dateadd = "";
        } else {
          var dateadd = "&date="+date;
        }
```

Comment: can you verify if the error is on a different line in your console?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's a difference between "undefined" and "undeclared" - it looks like in your code it doesn't exist, ie is undeclared.  https://jsfiddle.net/2om07p3d/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use something like this to verify whether variable is undefined or not

```
if (typeof something === "undefined") {
    alert("something is undefined");
}
```

Comment: using typeof doesn't cause the error for me.  So I am going with this.